# Sorting DataView rows by Column Name

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a JArray that is structured like the following:

```
JArray array = 
[
  { "Name": "Mike" },
  { "Age": 24 }
];
```

I'm creating a DataView with each JObject key as a Column name. I'd like to sort the rows by column name (horizontally). In the previous example, the columns would be ordered with Age coming before Name. Is there any way to do this with a DataView implementation? I'm also open to implementing the sort on the JArray beforehand, but am struggling since the keys are the sort values, and they're not known beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit awkward because your JArray isn't an array of like types. You'll need to unpick the individual elements and make some assumptions on the structure - for example, that each is a single `JProperty`.

Try something like this:

```
        var jArray = new JArray(
            new[] { 
                          new JObject(new JProperty("Name", "Mike")),
                          new JObject(new JProperty("Age", 24))
                  });

        var sortedJArray = new JArray(jArray.OrderBy(j => ((JObject)j).Properties().First().Name));
```

Does this give you what you need?